# How to integrate add-ons (.xpi) into my custom Firefox build?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I'm compiling Firefox 44.0.2 on my Windows machine using the official guidance: [Simple Firefox build](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Build_Instructions/Simple_Firefox_build). I want to integrate some custom add-ons to my build. The add-ons are usually `.xpi` files.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The [documented way to do this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Customizing_Firefox#Including_extensions_with_your_distribution_of_Firefox) is to include the *.xpi* file with the distribution in the directory:
*[Firefox install directory]/distribution/extensions*
The add-on will then be installed in (copied to) each profile upon the first use of that version of Firefox with the profile. The copy of the extension in each profile will be automatically updated using the normal auto-updating procedure. Effectively, the add-on will be treated as if separately installed in each profile. The user will not be asked to confirm installation of the add-on.

For more information see:

- [Customizing Firefox: Including extensions with your distribution of Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Customizing_Firefox#Including_extensions_with_your_distribution_of_Firefox) (MDN documentation)
- [Installing extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Installing_extensions) (MDN documentation)
- [Auto update of bundled Firefox extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37682010/auto-update-of-bundled-firefox-extensions/37759686#37759686) (Stackoverflow question)
- [Install WebExtensions on Firefox from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37728865/install-webextensions-on-firefox-from-the-command-line/37739112#37739112) (Stackoverflow question)

<sup>This answer was copied from my answer to [Integrating an add-on into a custom Firefox build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37608585/integrating-add-on-into-a-custom-firefox-build/37759845#37759845).</sup>