# How to have Firefox auto-update extensions bundled with an application

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

Our's company FF extension ships with the installation package of our application (i.e it's bundled with the application, not a Firefox build). During installation, the extension is currently added to Firefox by means of the Windows registry (a new key in the `HKCU/Software/Mozilla/Firefox/Extensions`).

My task is to enable auto-update for this extensions. To do that I've put `updateUrl` into *package.json*, created *update.rdf* along with the newer version of extension. As a result, Firefox finds an updated extension but fails to update it. Firefox logs:

```
1464888839764   addons.update-checker   DEBUG   Requesting https://path/update.rdf
1464888840017   addons.update-checker   DEBUG   Found an update entry for <My Addon Name> version 1.2.3
1464888840022   addons.xpi      DEBUG   Found an existing AddonInstall for <My Addon Name>
1464888840024   addons.manager  DEBUG   Found update for add-on <My Addon Name>
1464888840026   addons.manager  DEBUG   onUpdateFinished for <My Addon Name>
```

In contrast, if MyAddonName.xpi is installed manually (i.e. without the use of the Windows registry), auto-update works fine.

The questions is:
If Firefox deliberately skips auto-updating of registry-installed extensions, how can our bundled extension be installed with normal Firefox add-on auto-updating enabled?

So far I've found this: in *firefox-44.0\toolkit\mozapps\extensions\internal\XPIProvider.jsm*

```
if (!this._installLocation.locked && !this.pendingUninstall) {
  // Add-ons that are installed by a file link cannot be upgraded
  if (!this._installLocation.isLinkedAddon(this.id)) {
    permissions |= AddonManager.PERM_CAN_UPGRADE;
  }
  permissions |= AddonManager.PERM_CAN_UNINSTALL;
}
```

That is deliberate behavior of disabling update for add-ons that were installed from local folders.

We are working under some constraints:

- The installation must work for a Windows account with User permissions. In other words, %program files% is not writable, nor anything that requires permissions not granted to normal Users (i.e installation can not assume that the account has the expanded capabilities of a Power User, or Administrator).
- The bundled extension should be installed into all currently existing Firefox profiles for the user installing the application.
- Other users of the system should not be affected.
- The bundled extension should be auto-updated by Firefox through the normal process Firefox uses to automatically update add-ons.
- The auto-updating of the Firefox extension can not piggyback on any auto-updating capability that exists in our application. Such capability may, or may not, exist, but the normal Firefox add-on auto-updating capability must be used for the extension.
- We need a way to be able to disable the Firefox extension in all profiles from our application.

Comment: I have significantly modified your question to reflect my understanding of your situation and requirements from the comments we exchanged.  Please go over it and verify that what I put in is accurate. Obviously, make any changes you desire. The goal is to have a question that accurately reflects your situation and requirements so that any answers are applicable.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox is specifically designed with the assumption that any extension, such as yours, which is applied to multiple profiles by an install program external to the Firefox distribution will be updated by a process external to Firefox. This results in no solution which is clean and easy.

Given the constraints you are working under, the way I would accomplish what you desire is to have a loader extension which is installed either via placing it in the directory:
*%appdata%\Mozilla\Extensions\{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}*
Alternately, you can use the Windows registry as you currently do. However, using the Windows registry appears to be [considered obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Mozilla/Adding_extensions_using_the_Windows_registry). Using either method will result in the extension being installed in all currently existent profiles for the user and all newly created profiles.

In some situations the add-on will be installed and active without asking the user (restartless add-on, newly created profile, in directory), in other instances the user will be asked for permission to install the add-on (XUL overlay add-on, in directory, both newly created and existing profile). In yet other instances, the add-on will be entered in the add-on list as disabled (Windows registry, restartless add-on). I have not tested enough to determine a complete chart of the what the behavior is. I do not know what you desire the behavior to be. You will need to check to verify that the method used results in the loader extension being applied to Firefox profiles as you desire.

The function of the loader extension is to:

- Upon Firefox startup/extension install to check that all  extensions you desire/need exist as installed (not necessarily enabled). If any don't exist, then install them in the profile in the normal method for extensions (this will result in those extensions being automatically updated, but not the loader extension).
- You may also want it, through the options/preferences/[simple-prefs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/simple-prefs), to provide a way for the user to verify the installation of the needed extension(s) and enable/disable them.
- Its existence as an installed/enabled extension is used as a flag to your main extension(s) that it acceptable to run.  If the loader is not installed/enabled, your other extension disables/uninstalls itself. This covers how you can disable your main extension from your external application.

The extension(s) your loader add-on installs is/are the one(s) that you are currently bundling with your application.

The loader extension can install extensions either through direct file manipulation (not recommended), or using the [Add-on Manager](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Add-on_Manager). The Add-on Manager has methods for installing extensions from either a [file](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Add-on_Manager/AddonManager#getInstallForFile%28%29) or [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Add-on_Manager/AddonManager#getInstallForURL%28%29).

**Old understanding of question (extension bundled with Firefox build, or at least the ability to write to the Firefox install directory):**
Using the Windows registry to install bundled extensions is [considered obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Mozilla/Adding_extensions_using_the_Windows_registry). If you use the [currently documented method of bundling extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Customizing_Firefox#Including_extensions_with_your_distribution_of_Firefox), the extension file will be copied into the *extensions* directory of each profile upon profile creation, or the first run of that version of Firefox using that profile. From that time on, the extension will be automatically updated.

The correct directory to place bundled extensions (as *.xpi* files, not unpacked) in:
*[Firefox install directory]/distribution/extensions*

If you add extensions to that directory after a profile has been created and has run that version of Firefox, then the extension will not be copied to the *extensions* directory for that profile.

The user will have full control over the copy of the extension that is within their profile directory, including the ability to remove it from the profile. Other methods of installing the extension for multiple users/profiles will only permit them to disable it while not automatically updating.

**Current behavior:**
What Firefox does appears to be exactly what it should do and is as documented. If the extension is installed by an external agency (user, or install script, manually placing the file, or packaged with the Firefox build) by placing the reference (*.xpi* file, directory structure, file link, etc.) in a location from which multiple Firefox profiles might execute the extension without *copying* it into each profile (e.g. using the Windows registry), then it is assumed by Firefox that the external agency will take care of updating the add-on. In those cases, Firefox will not update the add-on.

I surmise that the reason for this is that any automatic updating occurs from within a specific profile (which is from a particular user on multi-user systems). It would be inappropriate for any specific profile/user to auto-update extensions that are in use by other profiles/users which might have the add-on file(s) locked or in-use. While Firefox breaks this by having the automatic updates of Firefox itself occur from within profiles, my assumption is that it was considered inappropriate for this to occur for extensions.

The options you have are to:

- Place the bundled extensions in the *[Firefox install location]/distribution/extensions* directory. This is the normal method of bundling extensions with a Firefox build.
- Put the extensions somewhere else ([multiple](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Installing_extensions) [possibilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37728865/install-webextensions-on-firefox-from-the-command-line/37739112#37739112)). You will need to have an additional method for your Firefox bundled install to check for updates to the extensions which are bundled with it.

By far the easiest is to include your bundled extensions in the *[Firefox install directory]/distribution/extensions* directory.

Comment: Thank you for such extended explanation! This is almost what I need. Except, placing XPI in the %[Firefox install directory]/distribution/extensions causes only _new_ user to see such extensions. The installer I'm working on is suppose to add extension for the current (i.e. already existing) user.

Comment: @RomanAlexandrov, You are bundling extensions with a version of Firefox. The extensions in that directory will be installed into any user/profile that runs with that version the first time it is run with that version of Firefox (not just when the profile is created). Already existing profiles do get the extension(s) installed without being prompted. If you want more options, either the link I provided as multiple possibilities, or [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37728865/install-webextensions-on-firefox-from-the-command-line/37739112#37739112).

Comment: @RomanAlexandrov, If you are still having issues, please provide more detail in your question. From your above comment it sounds like you are wanting to distribute a new bundle containing the *exact* same version of Firefox as already distributed and installed on some machines.  Is this accurate? If so, would it be reasonable to do a sub-sub-version roll of the Firefox version number (e.g. something like from 46.0.1 to 46.0.1.1)? Alternately, you could just put the *.xpi* files into the *extensions* directory of all currently existing profiles (see links in previously comment for directories).

Comment: I am sorry for not being totally clear on that. By 'bundled extension' I meant an application which bundles Firefox extension with its installer. It not Firefox bundle.

Comment: @RomanAlexandrov, Ironically, the way that I first wrote an answer, but never saved, is one way that will work for that case. However, Firefox really expects your application to handle updating the extension without any automaton on the part of Firefox. Do you have an auto-update process for your application? If so, then that should be used to update the Firefox extension which is bundled with it.

Comment: @RomanAlexandrov, From your comments: It appears you have an application, not Firefox. As part of that application you include a Firefox extension. Your application does not have a method to auto-update itself (or the updates for the Firefox extension are not in sync with updates to your application) (which?, or something else??). You are wanting to have Firefox auto-update just the Firefox extension which is bundled with your application.  Is this correct?

Comment: this is totally correct. I have an application which ships with Firefox extensions. During application life-time users are allowed to disable/enable this extension. But I want to update application itself and extension separately. Addons.mozilla.com hosting is not acceptable because I cannot add URL as a new a extension. So I decided to use updateURL feature to self-host new extensions.

Comment: @RomanAlexandrov, Does your application have auto-update capability for itself? (I'm assuming not, but I could be wrong.) Is your Firefox extension, or the updates for it, hosted on AMO, or on your own site?

Comment: @RomanAlexandrov, One method would be to have a loader extension and your actual application extension. The loader would be installed the way you currently install your extension. Its only responsibility is to, upon Firefox startup, check to see if your main extension is installed in that profile. If your main extension is not installed, then install it through the normal Firefox install process so it is installed in that profile and updates normally.  The install could be either with a file included with the bundle, or that is downloaded.

Comment: My application must be operable by regular users, which do not have write access to the 'Program Files' folder. All updatable files of the application are stored in user's profile directory. As for the hosting: I've already setup self-hosting updates https server.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Firefox's JS capabilities. It is possible to install one extension from another extension? And the second question: I also need an option to disable extension from the application. Currently it's done by removing registry code. But having loader extension and main extension how can application disable main extension?

Comment: @RomanAlexandrov, Ok.  Unless I have misunderstood something about your situation, then the way I would do it is as described in my most recent prior comment with a loader/installer extension and a main extension.  Perhaps with one change in that I might choose to install the loader extension into the user's *%appdata%\Mozilla\Extensions\{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}\* directory rather than use the Windows registry. The main reason for doing so is that using the registry appears to be considered obsolete.

Comment: @RomanAlexandrov, Yes, add-ons can install other add-ons, through either direct file manipulation or the [Add-on Manager](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Add-on_Manager#Installing_new_add-ons) that is specifically designed to do so from either a [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Add-on_Manager/AddonManager#getInstallForURL%28%29), or [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Add-on_Manager/AddonManager#getInstallForFile%28%29), etc.

Comment: @RomanAlexandrov, I am at the end of my day. I'll fold the information and suggested method from these comments into my answer in about 12 hours, or so.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help. Overall it seems there are  no out-of-the-box solutions. Either I'll have to search for user profiles and put XPI there, or develop additional loader extension.

Comment: @RomanAlexandrov, I'm glad to have been of help.  Unfortunately, searching for user profiles does not solve the problem of having the extension in new profiles created after the install of your application.  You stated that you can not assume that *[Firefox install location]/distribution/extensions* is writable to you during install.  Thus, that is not a valid possibility to cover that case (even if you cover the case of possibly having multiple *[Firefox install location]* directories.

Comment: @RomanAlexandrov, BTW: I am currently assuming that your install only installs for a single user, but is supposed to cover all profiles for that one user. Is that accurate?

Comment: @RomanAlexandrov, I have updated this answer to reflect the comments, including the need to be able to disable the extension from the external application (which I missed as a requirement yesterday).

Comment: Current behavior of my software is as per user profile. In a case of a new profile creation (or switching to another) user should hit 'Enable plugin' button in the UI to activate extension. This is due to a fact that obsolete registry installation method uses HKCU hive. So, that means that searching and adding XPI directly to the current user's profile is an acceptable solution as it won't degrade quality of user experience. Thank you again for all your help!