# Updating an unlisted Firefox WebExtension installed using the Windows registry not working

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I've been trying to distribute a Firefox WebExtension using the Windows Registry as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Alternative_distribution_options/Add-ons_in_the_enterprise). However, when trying to update the extension, it doesn't seem to work.

The extension's manifest points at my update.json file:

```
"applications": {
    "gecko": {
        "id": "extensionTest@extension.com",
        "update_url": "https://cooldomain.com/update.json",
    }
}
```

And my update.json file points at a new version:

```
{
    "addons": {
        "extensionTest@extension.com": {
            "updates": [{
                "version": "2.5.6",
                "update_link": "https://cooldomain.com/extensionTest-2.5.6-an%2Bfx.xpi"
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Checking the browser console, it indeed gets the update.json file, and then... nothing happens. Is there a way to check in Firefox what error occurred during the update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add-ons installed using the Windows Registry are exempt from the Mozilla update process. If you install using the Windows Registry, Mozilla assumes that your application will handle all updates (i.e. not Firefox). When installed using the Windows Registry, or any other way where the extension is *run* from a single location (in contrast to being copied into each profile), Firefox will not update your extension.

Firefox is functioning as designed. Thus, there is no error.

For more information see: [How to have Firefox auto-update extensions bundled with an application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37759686/3773011)

Comment: ok, so this is slightly outside the scope of the question, but does the linked answer applies to webextensions (instead of XUL)? Because in Mozilla's documentation (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Alternative_distribution_options/Sideloading_add-ons) they specify that installing the extension through a folder will result in no automatic updates (they didn't specify it for registry deployment, which is why I thought THIS was the valid method to deploy unlisted extensions with auto-update capability).

Comment: Firefox doesn't handle updating WebExtensions differently than legacy extensions. Doing so would just be extra work on something already working as desired. Re: auto-updating: answer is a bit complex. Generally, if the extension would be *run* in multiple profiles (if such existed) from the place in which it's installed, then Firefox doesn't auto-update. If the extension file is *copied* (from where it's initially installed into the Firefox distribution) into each profile's *extensions* directory and then run from there, then Firefox will auto-update each copy per the settings in that profile.

Comment: so if I understand correctly, using the profile directory at '\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*' to copy the extension to _existing_ installation should install it to that profile and have auto-updates enabled, right?

Comment: If you mean on Windows, the *extensions* directory in the profile directories is one of the places you could put it. If you are doing it with Administrator privileges, you can also put it in a directory in the Firefox install directory and it will be copied by Firefox into each profile. It's really too complex for a decent answer in comments.