# Install WebExtensions on Firefox from the command line

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, command-line-interface

I found the question [How to install Firefox addon from command line in scripts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73474/how-to-install-firefox-addon-from-command-line-in-scripts) that seems to work for Firefox extensions (i.e. ones with an *install.rdf* file) but what about WebExtensions (extension with a *manifest.json* file instead)?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Please see:

- [Installing extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Installing_extensions)
- [Customizing Firefox: Including extensions with your distribution of Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Customizing_Firefox#Including_extensions_with_your_distribution_of_Firefox)

The question you link on askubuntu: [How to install Firefox addon from command line in scripts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73474/how-to-install-firefox-addon-from-command-line-in-scripts) is several years out of date, but does have some good information.

At this point, most Mozilla add-ons, including all Firefox WebExtension add-ons, are installed manually by placing the add-on's `.xpi` file in the appropriate directory with the correct name for the extension without unpacking (unzipping) the contents. [You can also install them by downloading them in Firefox, drag-and-drop the `.xpi` onto Firefox/Thunderbird, etc.]

You can determine those add-ons that must be unpacked by unpacking the add-on's `.xpi` file and looking at the [`install.rdf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Install_Manifests) file to see if it has [`<em:unpack>true</em:unpack>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Install_Manifests#unpack). All WebExtensions don't have this file and are installed without unpacking.

The `.xpi` file must be called `[extensionID].xpi`. You can find the extension ID from either the `install.rdf` file (non-WebExtension add-ons). In that file, you are looking for [`<em:id>ThisEntireStringIsTheAddOnsID</em:id>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Install_Manifests#id)

For a WebExtension, the ID is in the [`manifest.json`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json) file under the [applications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/applications) property:

```
"applications": {
    "gecko": {
        "id": "ThisEntireStringIsTheAddOnsID"
    }
},
```

For both of the above examples the `.xpi` file must be renamed to `ThisEntireStringIsTheAddOnsID.xpi`

If the `install.rdf` file includes `<em:unpack>true</em:unpack>`, then the files in the `.xpi` must be unpacked (unzipped) and placed in a subdirectory under the extensions directory.  In the above `install.rdf` example (again WebExtensions are **not** unpacked), the directory would be named: `ThisEntireStringIsTheAddOnsID`

### Extension directories:

The extension directories where you put the `.xpi` file or unpacked directory are (information partially [copied from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Installing_extensions)):

For all users running a particular version of Firefox:
`[Firefox install directory]/browser/extensions/`

Firefox will ask the user to confirm installation of the add-on when that version of Firefox is run. The user will not have the ability to remove the extension, only disable it. The extension will not be automatically updated.

For all users running a particular version of Firefox:
`[Firefox install directory]/distribution/extensions`

The extension will be installed for all users/profiles the first time the profile is run with that version of Firefox. The extension will be copied into the profile's `extensions` directory and the user will be able to remove it in addition to disabling it. The user will not be asked to confirm installation. The extension copied to each profile will be automatically updated along with all other extensions installed for that profile. You should **not** unpack any `.xpi` files in this directory. If the file needs to be unpacked, it will be done automatically by Firefox when the extension is installed in each profile.

For a particular User's specific profile:
`[profile directory]/extensions/`

**On Windows:**
All profiles for a specific user:
`<I>%appdata%\\Mozilla\\Extensions\\{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}\</I>`

Profile directories are located at:
`<i>\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\*</i>`

**OSX:**
For all users:
`/Library/Application Support/Mozilla/Extensions/{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}/`

Just for a specific user, place it in that user's library folder hierarchy:
`~/Library/Application Support/Mozilla/Extensions/{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}/`

**Linux:**
For all users:
`/usr/lib/Mozilla/extensions/{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}/`

or
`/usr/lib64/Mozilla/extensions/{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}/`

or
`/usr/share/Mozilla/extensions/{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}/`

Just for a specific user:
`~/.Mozilla/extensions/{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}/`

### NOTE:

The `-install-global-extension` option mentioned in the question/answer you linked was [removed from Firefox as of Gecko 1.9.2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options#Add-ons) ( a long time ago).

Comment: what is necessary files for WebExtensions  I build addons but how to pack that into  .xpi  I don't know (I try to make .zip and rename it to .xpi) but when I install that that give an error - "This add-on could not be installed because it appears to be corrupt."  it work fine in debug mode(unpacked) @Makyen

Comment: @DivyeshKanzariya, This sounds like it might be more involved than should be addressed in just a set of comments. You will probably want to create a separate question for this.  We are going to need more information including, at least, a list of all the files you are attempting to use and the exact hierarchy that you are using in your *.xpi* file (perhaps even a link to where it could be downloaded). Also knowing the version of Firefox you are using would be helpful.

Comment: I came across an addon, disconnect, https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/disconnect/ ,  whose `manifest.json` doesn't include the `applications` property. How do I determine the filename in this case?

Comment: @erjoalgo, That's a good question. I don't have the time to take a good look at it at the moment.  The correct file name *2.0@disconnect.me.xpi* only exists in the *META-INF\mozilla.rsa* file. I'd have to did through the source code to be sure that's where it is obtained. It should be noted that this add-on is one that existed in multiple versions prior to the WebExtensions based version.

Comment: The links above do not work anymore. The closest I could find on the mozilla site is https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/deploying-firefox-with-extensions - maybe it's a starting point. Another illuminating link would be: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1364066 - **beware**: above method seems to be working on *Firefox for enterprises*, for "normal" firefox on your home workstation put global webextensions in `[installpath]/extenstions/{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}/ID.xpi` (no curly braces around `ID`; end with `.xpi`; for linux install path: try `/local/share/mozilla`)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like downloading & putting an addon.xpi somewhere and Firefox loading it does not work anymore at all:

https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2020/03/10/support-for-extension-sideloading-has-ended/