# How to pack an addon with firefox custom build

Tags: linux, firefox, firefox-addon

OS: Ubuntu 16 64 bit

I am trying to build firefox from scratch for Ubuntu. I have downloaded the source code and built it as explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Build_Instructions/Simple_Firefox_build/Linux_and_MacOS_build_preparation). Building was successful and a I was greeted with a fresh firefox welcome screen when I ran `mach run`.

I was planning to add custom addons and change the GUI a bit to create a customized version of Firefox. So I had the `xpi` files of some addons that I wanted. To add add-ons during building,according to the Mozilla docs,we need to add the extensions in the distribution/extensions folder.

I have looked in the source code directory structure for this directory and found it in the source code root as shown here.
[image]

I placed these `xpi` files directly to that folder and built Firefox again but couldn't find the add-on integrated when `mach run` is executed.

My second thought was to add the `xpi` files to the `extensions` folder generated by the build process. i.e under the `src/mozilla-central/obj-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/extensions` folder. I placed them there and executed `mach run` again and still I was unsuccessful.

Then I found that the final Firefox executable lies under the directory `src/mozilla-central/obj-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/dist/bin` from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wpRckI9IfUM). So I manually created a folder named `extensions` and placed the `xpi`s there. Again unsuccessful.

Now I am out of ideas. How to achieve this? I couldn't find any other docs that explains this. May be I missed something. Could someone help me to achieve this?

Comment: Did you rename the add-on file as *addonID.xpi*, based on the add-on ID specified in the add-on's *install.rdf*, or *manifest.json*?

Comment: Related/duplicates: [How to integrate add-ons (.xpi) into my custom Firefox build?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35788485), and [Integrating an add-on into a custom Firefox build](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37608585), but neither have up-voted or accepted answers so can not be used as valid close-as-duplicate targets.

Answer (score 3):

The [documented way to do this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Customizing_Firefox#Including_extensions_with_your_distribution_of_Firefox) is to include the *.xpi* file with the distribution in the directory:
*[Firefox install directory]/distribution/extensions*
The add-on will then be installed in (copied to) each profile upon the first use of that version of Firefox with the profile. The copy of the extension in each profile will be automatically updated using the normal auto-updating procedure. Effectively, the add-on will be treated as if separately installed in each profile. The user will not be asked to confirm installation of the add-on.

The add-on file name must be in the form of *addonID.xpi*, where addonID is the add-on ID which is defined in the [`<em:id>` field](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Install_Manifests#id) in the add-on's *install.rdf* file. For WebExtensions based extensions this is the add-on ID defined in the [`applications.gecko.id` field](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/applications) in the *manifest.json*.

It also works if you put the add-on *.xpi* file in the *[Firefox install directory]/browser/extensions* directory. However, any [unpacked extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Install_Manifests#unpack) must be placed here in an unpacked state (i.e. unpacked from the *.xpi* file).

For more information see:

- [Customizing Firefox: Including extensions with your distribution of Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Customizing_Firefox#Including_extensions_with_your_distribution_of_Firefox) (MDN documentation)
- [Installing extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Installing_extensions) (MDN documentation)
- [Auto update of bundled Firefox extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37682010/auto-update-of-bundled-firefox-extensions/37759686#37759686) (Stackoverflow question)
- [Install WebExtensions on Firefox from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37728865/install-webextensions-on-firefox-from-the-command-line/37739112#37739112) (Stackoverflow question)

<sup>This answer was copied from my answer to [Integrating an add-on into a custom Firefox build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37608585/integrating-add-on-into-a-custom-firefox-build/37759845#37759845), then modified.</sup>