# Firefox extension not functional when installed using HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MozillaPlugins

Tags: firefox-addon

I have registered my Firefox extension using the Windows registry under:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MozillaPlugins
```

But, upon restarting Firefox I do not not see my extension installed.

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: Please provide the actual registry entries you used and at least your *install.rdf* or *manifest.json* file. Better, would be an [MCVE]. Without this information, your question could be considered to be off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

An [extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons) is not a [plugin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Plugins).  You are using the wrong location within the Windows registry to add an add-on/extension.

Using registry entries to install add-ons is [considered obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Mozilla/Adding_extensions_using_the_Windows_registry).  However, if you are going to do so, the registry key you should be using for the current user is:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Mozilla\Firefox\Extensions
```

MDN provides the following information as to what the content of the registry entry under that key should be:

> The [ID](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Install_Manifests#id) of the extension must be used as the name of the Registry entry. The Registry entry must have a type of REG_SZ, and its value must be an absolute path to the folder containing the extension (i.e., the location of the unpacked XPI). For example, to install the extension described in the [Building an Extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Building_an_Extension) article, create a Registry entry with name equal to `sample@foo.net` and value equal to `c:\extensions\myExtension`.

You have not included in the question the exact entries you have used in the registry nor the contents of your add-on including the directory it is located in and, at least, the contents of your *install.rdf* file or *manifest.json* file. Thus, it is not possible for us to know if there is another issue in addition to, or instead of, your use of the wrong registry key.

**Installation options other than using the Windows registry:**
Multiple alternatives to using the registry exist.  You can install your extension into one, or more of the possible directories.  Depending on which location you use to install, the add-on may, or may not, be automatically updated by Firefox when you release a new version. If you use the Windows registry it will not be automatically updated.

Within the following links along with the official information from MDN, you will find a list of locations in which you can install the extension to have it affect the current user or all users on the machine, and if it will be automatically updated.

- [Adding Extensions using the Windows Registry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Mozilla/Adding_extensions_using_the_Windows_registry) (MDN documentation)
- [Installing extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Installing_extensions) (MDN documentation)
- [Install WebExtensions on Firefox from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37728865/install-webextensions-on-firefox-from-the-command-line/37739112#37739112) (Stackoverflow question)
- [Including extensions with your distribution of Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Customizing_Firefox#Including_extensions_with_your_distribution_of_Firefox) (MDN documentation)
- [Extension Packaging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Extension_Packaging) (MDN documentation)
- [How to have Firefox auto-update extensions bundled with an application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37682010/how-to-have-firefox-auto-update-extensions-bundled-with-an-application/37759686#37759686) (Stackoverflow question)
- [How to integrate add-ons (.xpi) into my custom Firefox build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35788485/how-to-integrate-add-ons-xpi-into-my-custom-firefox-build/37759890#37759890) (Stackoverflow question)

Comment: Thnx , now i am able install my extension using command line. I have another question. I want to make window installer package of  extension(.xpi package) ,it is signed and unlisted. How to create it ? So when i will install .exe ,my extension will be installed in firefox.?