# How to add custom build extension permanently on firefox modifying the source code

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I need to build a firefox browser with custom configurations such as modifying the brand name, log etc. I successfully modified name and logo but could not figure out how to add a custom extension such that when firefox is built the extension is automatically integrated.

I tried adding extensions in browser/extension directory and modifying the config files but no success. I searched about this problem all over the internet but could not find an appropriate solution so any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Related/duplicate: "[How to integrate add-ons (.xpi) into my custom Firefox build?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35788485/3773011)" Much of the documentation I linked in my answer to that question is no longer available. I haven't recently tested to see if things have changed.

Comment: @Makyen I want to integrate the extension while building the firefox. In chromium it was simple I needed to place the crx file in extension folder and tweak some other codes but in firefox I don't know where I should make the change. Also the documentation is no longer available.